# Correct one-liner list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following list and string:

```
words = ['AIBONITO', 'BICINIUM', 'LIMONIUM', 'PICKNICK', 'SILENIUM', 'TITANIUM']
letters = 'ADEOLR'
```

I want to delete items in the list that contain a letter in the string. The following code does just that.

code:

```
for letter in letters:
    for word in words:
        if letter in word:
            words.remove(word)
print(words)
```

output:

```
['BICINIUM', 'PICKNICK']
```

Now I would like to convert it to a one-liner. I tried to do it by using the following code:

```
print([words for letter in letters for word in words if letter not in word])
```

This gives me a list with 12 items all containing ['BICINIUM', 'PICKNICK']. What do I need to change in the one-liner to obtain the same output as the first piece of code?

I know I can add "[0]" at the end of the one-liner but that's not really clean.

Comment: You should never alter the containers you're iterating through. You could create a copy of the words list and modify that.

Comment: List comprehensions *create* new lists; they don't modify existing lists.

Comment: [Your loop doesn't actually work](https://ideone.com/98PtyB), because you're structurally modifying `words` while iterating over it.

Comment: I am referring to the first piece of code you posted, not the list comprehension you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your list comprehension uses `words`, not `word`, as the expression that adds a value to the list. `[word for letter ...]`, not `[words for letter ...]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `all` allows to do that.

```
words = ['AIBONITO', 'BICINIUM', 'LIMONIUM', 'PICKNICK', 'SILENIUM', 'TITANIUM']
letters = 'ADEOLR'

result = [word for word in words if all(letter not in word for letter in letters)]
```

yields:

```
['BICINIUM', 'PICKNICK']
```

An alternative uses a `set` of letters for the same result:

```
letters = set('ADEOLR')

result = [word for word in words if letters.isdisjoint(word)]
```

Comment: the `isdisjoint` approach is the faster I think

Comment: yes because it "short circuits" as soon as an intersection is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = set(letters)
[word for word in words if len(set(word).intersection(letters))==0]

#['BICINIUM', 'PICKNICK']
```

Comment: okay but 1) creating a set of letters each time (intersection does that) is not the most efficient, and 2) creating the intersection itself is not necessary. Use `isdisjoint` instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you right